# Is there a way to dynamically change navbar text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" align="center"><img src="img/VAWE-long-300x30-transparent.png" width="300" height="30" alt="" /></div>
    <div data-role="content" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
        <div id="wowslider-container1" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
            <div class="ws_images">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/catering_1.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1_0" /></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/rev._pamela_a._mann.png" alt="wowslider.com" title="" id="wows1_1" /></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/catering.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1_2" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
        <div style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <img src="img/Wedding in a Box.png" style="width:100%!important;">
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <img src="img/Flutter My Shutter.png" style="width:100%!important;">
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <img src="img/Brock's riverside.png" style="width:100%!important;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-nodisc-icon">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-top ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-icon-calendar ui-btn-icon-top">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-top">Vendors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#map" class="ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-top">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="loginCheck()" class="ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-top">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if there is a way I can change the "Vendors" menu item as shown above, and change the text and icon to something different using jQuery in a pageinit function?

Comment: In short, yes there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried on pageinit doing something like `$(".vendorOption").find('ui-btn-text').text('Messages');` but to no avail.

Comment: Did you understand what that was doing? you dont appear to have either a `.vendorOption` classed element, nor a `ui-btn-text` element.

Comment: You could just easily give what you want to be changed an ID, and then grab it with jQuery and use `$("#YOURID").text();`!

Comment: Sorry I just realized that those were removed in the code I posted. I have them there. But to answer your question, no I don't exactly understand what it was doing. I have a good understanding of jQuery but some of the more advanced things like this elude me.

Comment: Ok, no problem. While i wouldnt consider selectors an "advanced" thing, sometimes they can get complex. Is there a reason you cant directly edit the HTML without the need for JS?

Comment: I need to make this so a user can login from a different page in the DOM, go back to the main page, and then the middle button changes from Vendors to Messages because the user IS a vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would find an a element with the string Vendors in it, replace that string. It then can remove the class for the icon and replace it with something else.

```
$("a:contains('Vendors')").text('Different String');
$("a:contains('Vendors')").removeClass('ui-icon-search').addClass('ui-icon-location');
```

Comment: Trying this. And to make a point, I totally get how this code works.

Comment: you can chain your functions without having to perform the selector again (ie. straight after the `.text()` function you can call `.removeClass`. You're also missing a closing `'` from your `.addClass`

Comment: Alright so I have this put in but the problem I now face is this: I start at the home page #page1 with that button saying "Vendors", then if the user logs into a Vendor account on page #login successfully, it goes back to #page1, but it does not change "Vendors" to "Messages". I think it's because the page is still cached in the DOM even though I don't use `data-prefetch` or `data-dom-cache = "true"`

Comment: There, I got it to work, I had to set my dynamic page transition from #login to #page1 to reload: "true", as follows: `$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page1", { transition: "pop", reload: "true"});`

Comment: One point to add though to this. One has to actually change the text of the navbar item AFTER the icon class is removed and then re-added otherwise it will not find the item because it no longer exists under a:contains('Vendors')